# How to fetch more than one record using case in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
 1) fk_tblUserEmployeeList
 2) fk_tblmanageremployeelist
```

In these two tables one column is common that is `userid` and I am getting `userid` from the UI. I want a record for `userid` from the first table. If there is none, get the record for the same `userid` from the second table..

I am trying to use `CASE`, but I get an error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Below is my query:

```
select case when ( select count(userid) 
                   from fk_tblUserEmployeeList 
                   where userid=1
                 ) > 1 
            then ( select employeeid 
                   from fk_tblUserEmployeeList 
                   where userid=1
                 )
            else ( select employeeid 
                   from fk_tblmanageremployeelist 
                   where userid=1
                 ) 
       end
```

Comment: Note that the `>` should actually be `>=` - otherwise, if you have exactly one matching record, it will still use the else condition.

Comment: In addition to what @Mark said, the original query could never work at all without a `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 1):

With the code that you presented, the result from the `case` will have more than one `row`. That'll give an error because of the `select` previously to the `case`. You can't `select` several `rows` in there.

```
select

case when (select count(userid) from fk_tblUserEmployeeList where userid=1) > 1
    then (select employeeid from fk_tblUserEmployeeList where userid=1)
    else (select employeeid from fk_tblmanageremployeelist where userid=1)
end
```

So, to avoid this, you can use [IF](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

It should be something like this:

```
IF (select count(userid) from fk_tblUserEmployeeList where userid=1) > 1 THEN
    (select employeeid from fk_tblUserEmployeeList where userid=1)
ELSE
    (select employeeid from fk_tblmanageremployeelist where userid=1)
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select employeeid 
from fk_tblUserEmployeeList 
where userid=1
union all
select employeeid 
from fk_tblmanageremployeelist
where userid=1 and
not exists (select null
            from fk_tblUserEmployeeList 
            where userid=1)
```

Note that the `not exists` clause is unnecessary if no user is ever present on both tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select employeeid 
    from fk_tblUserEmployeeList 
    where userid = 1
      and ( select count(*) 
            from fk_tblUserEmployeeList 
            where userid=1
          ) > 1
  union all
    select employeeid 
    from fk_tblmanageremployeelist 
    where userid = 1
      and ( select count(*) 
            from fk_tblUserEmployeeList 
            where userid = 1
          ) <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will be simplest and fastest:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
        (SELECT employeeid FROM fk_tblUserEmployeeList    WHERE userid = 1),
        (SELECT employeeid FROM fk_tblmanageremployeelist WHERE userid = 1))
```

If `userid` is not **UNIQUE**, you'll have to add a method to pick one row, Like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
        (SELECT employeeid
         FROM   fk_tblUserEmployeeList
         WHERE  userid = 1
         ORDER  BY employeeid
         LIMIT  1),
        (SELECT employeeid
         FROM   fk_tblmanageremployeelist
         WHERE  userid = 1
         ORDER  BY employeeid
         LIMIT  1)
        )
```